# Best way to integrate existing Python tools with Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have number of Python tools that I run, mostly for scraping websites or pulling data from various web APIs.

Currently they are all run from bash with the parameters passed as command line arguments e.g.

```
$ python my_tool.py -arg1 -arg2 --output foobar.json
```

I want to move away from using the command line and instead run the tools via a web interface. My aim is to have a setup where a user can authenticate to the website, enter the arguments via a web form, click to run the tools, and have the returned json data to a database for later analysis.

I've chosen Django as a framework for the web interface and db since I already have experience with Python. However I'm seeking advice as to best practice for integrating the Python tools I already have with Django. Am I best to integrate the tools directly as Django apps, or keep them separate but with a means to communicate with Django? I'd be grateful for the advice and experience of others on this one.

Comment: Can you add these scripts in your Django project? And instead of it as a command line script, you can import the functions and just call them as any other python method.
You can also use Django Management Commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Thanks @JoVi. Technically I don't see a reason why they can't be added in as regular functions. They're all quite lightweight.

Thanks for the tip on Management Commands, I wasn't aware of them (still learning my way through...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you definitely must create a package containing all your scripts.
If you should include or exclude from the app, it deppends. If your scripts are intended to be used all accross the project, the package has to be outside the app otherwise inside.

```
Inside the app
    ├── scrape
    │   ├── db_tools
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── scrape_etc.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── forms.py

Outside the app
   ├── db_tools
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── scrape_etc.py
   ├── some_app
   └── other_app
```

As an additional note, in case the output be time consuming you could create background tasks (using celery) and send the result by email or store someplace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: Celery. I've upvoted buy my account is too new to register it.

Answer (score 0):

## maintenance of API and its code

Good news, you have lots of options!

You used to invoke `my_tool.py` from bash.
Perhaps it starts with [`import typer`](https://pypi.org/project/typer/).
Definitely it is working now,
and is well tested.

In future most invocations
(all invocations?) will be via web.

Bad news, the bits will rot as months go by.
The tool will sprout new features,
and acquire bug fixes.
An interface that is not regularly tested
is one that will eventually behave less
predictably than desired.

Here's the **decision** you are now faced
with making:

How will folks call the tool's code in future?

That is, what is the supported way to call it?
There are some choices available.

### 1. keep the CLI interface

The CLI API is already supported and working.
You might even have automated tests that
exercise it, verifying all is well.
Perhaps there are multiple callers,
such as production users at bash prompt,
developers at bash prompt, Makefiles,
cron jobs.
Web becomes just one more caller.

You might choose to preserve this status quo,
and *additionally* support having a web server
fork / exec the tool as a child process.
At least one advantage is that, in the event
of resource leak, the tool is a short-lived
process which releases resources upon exiting.
A disadvantage is the need to re-import
python libraries, which in some cases can
take more than one second.

### 2. support both

As months go by there *will* be new features
added, and some of them might tack on new
args to the existing API.

Commit to supporting both CLI & web as
first-class consumers of the code.
Take care to add automated tests for both,
and run them with each release.

This suggests that django will call into
public methods within the same process.
That should be faster, as imports and
datastructures are already initialized.
We hope there's no resource leaks.

### 3. web only

Abandon / desupport the CLI interface,
to save support costs.

Note that you will *still* need
automated tests, to instill confidence
in new releases down the road.
You might find that CLI support would come
in handy during testing phase.

---

In the end, the decision is yours.
Life is full of trade-offs.

Comment: Thankyou. I would upvote but my account is too new.